# How to declare KeyStroke - pressed and released?

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

I want to know how to declare new `KeyStroke`  - pressed and released? For example I can do:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("pressed F10");
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released F10");
```

But how to write in a way like this?:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a method with an additional boolean argument for this

[`KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(int keyCode, int modifiers, boolean onKeyRelease)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

The method you discovered works on key press, so this:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0);
```

is equivalent to

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0, false);
```

---

If you want to get this working on the release of <kbd>F10</kbd>, use

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F10, 0, true);
```